# How to dynamically Update a text-box in a different page when the value changed using Local Storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume I have two web pages. In page A, I have a button to change a value in the local storage as follows.

```
localStorage.setItem('key', key);
```

This **key** is a random String which is generated when the button click.
Therefore each time when the button is clicked it change the localStorage value. in page B I have a textbox which should dynamically change its value when the value of the key in the local storage get changed.

It should happen when I have opened the two pages in two tabs in my browser.

Can I use an event Listener for that?
If so how to implement that ?

Comment: Does this page a and page b belong to same application..which are in same domain??

Comment: You can access localstorage without binding it to the window also.It works.

Comment: yes they are in same domain in same applicatiom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(window).bind('storage', function (e) {
      console.log(e.originalEvent.key, e.originalEvent.newValue);
 });
```

This will do the trick

Comment: where should I call this function?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can bind the `storage` event in `jQuery`

```
$(window).bind('storage', function (e) {
     //Handle it here
  });
```

Whenever there is a change in `localStorage`, this event will be invoked.